# ADO Delivery Plans

Tags: ado

[ADO Delivery Plans Roll Up View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd1JB.png)

We are planning to use delivery plans to track our roadmap and progress in ADO. And I had a question w.r.t the roll up Card View.

In the % complete for stories, bugs, features etc., I need it to count "Done" and an additional state added by my team called "released". Is it possible to do this? Please see attached for more context.

We tried to add this via delivery plan settings and It did not work. Seemed to all items on del plan view.